UniswapV3 deployments without the governance on new L3 chains
i am planning to deploy the exact clone of uniswapv3 on a l3 chain which is based on l2(Base mainnet) but as i was doing little research i read a little about the governance contract in uniswap.
can some one explain in what is the use of governance contract in the uniswapv3 and how would i deploy the clone without the governance or is it even possible to deploy without the governance?

The best idea of what governance contract does you can get by reading the Uniswap governance forum posts.
Some obvious ones

Turning on the fee switch
Setting pool fee tiers


You can ignore the existence of the governance unless you want to switch on the protocol fees or enable different pool fees.
The governance is just the owner of UniswapV3Factory, and it's initially set to the deployer. You can change it using the setOwner function.
